# Combinations / Permutations (Inclusive/Exclusive Principle) Questions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So I'm working on some combination and permutation problems, and I thought I had a decent handle on them, but this next set I'm getting impossible answers. Can someone look through and let me know where I'm way off, maybe point in the right direction? I still have much to learn!

Question: A bagel shop has bagels in 6 varieties. Assuming there are at least 20 bagels of each variety, how many ways are there to choose 20 bagels...

A) With no restrictions:
$$C(20+6-1,20) = C(25,20) = 53130$$
Seems reasonable, pretty sure I'm correct.

B) With at least two of each variety:
$$6*C(20,2)*C(8+6-1,8) = 2427$$
I say 6*C(20,2) because there are 6 varieties and we're choosing 2 of each, then we have 8 left to pick out of the 6 varieties. This seems prone to error. It is however smaller than A, which is a good thing.

C) With three or fewer blueberry bagels: The way I chose to solve this problem is by complement. The total number  choices (found in A) minus the number of ways you can pick with 4 or more blueberry bagels (complement of 3 or less) and it looks something like this. It is horribly incorrect, and I'm not sure why.
$$C(25,20) - 6 * C(16+6-1,16)= - 1,147,182$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A) is correct. For (B), the 12 "fixed" bagels can be ignored, so there are 8 bagels and 5 separators and the $6\binom{20}2$ multiplier is incorrect; there are just $\binom{8+6-1}8=1287$ ways.

For (C), the $6\binom{21}{16}$ should instead be $\binom{21}5$ – the number of ways to have at least four blueberry bagels in the selection, leaving 16 bagels but still six varieties:
$$\binom{25}5-\binom{21}5=32781$$

Comment: do you use 5 bagels instead of 6 because we are already counting the blueberry?

Comment: @Podo Yes.${}{}{}$

Comment: If we keep the "separators" as the lower, index, e.g. $\binom{25}5, \binom{13}5$, it doesn't matter for $A$ and $B$, but $C$ becomes much simpler, preplace $4$ blueberries to deliberately violate constraints and subtract inadmissible ways, thus $\binom{25}5 - \binom{21}5$

Comment: @trueblueanil Good catch.